# More direct way to tidy a data frame with two similar columns?

Tags: r, dataframe, merge, duplicates, multiple-columns

I am making a reference table to easily convert between identifiers and different versions of those identifiers. I have a merged table with multiple columns containing ids from multiple versions of a database (`ipi_id.x` & `ipi_id.y`, test `df` below:

```
    protein_id    ipi_id.x numbers      ensembl_id hgnc_number hgnc_symbol entrez_id    ipi_id.y uniprot
    1       ATP6 IPI00552036       3 ENSG00000198899        7414     MT-ATP6      4508 IPI00954924  P00846
    2       ATP6 IPI00552036       3 ENSG00000198899        7414     MT-ATP6      4508 IPI00743734  P00846
    3       ATP6 IPI00552036       3 ENSG00000198899        7414     MT-ATP6      4508 IPI00654820  P00846
    4       COX2 IPI00916440       1 ENSG00000198712        7421      MT-CO2      4513 IPI00930721  P00403
    5       COX2 IPI00916440       1 ENSG00000198712        7421      MT-CO2      4513 IPI00017510  P00403
```

The two columns ipi_id.x and .y have different versioned identifiers for the same entries and I would like them to be in the same column, but with added rows containing the rest of the information so that each ipi_id has its own row. Result `df` below:

```
    protein_id    ipi_id   numbers      ensembl_id hgnc_number hgnc_symbol entrez_id   uniprot
    1       ATP6 IPI00552036       3 ENSG00000198899        7414     MT-ATP6      4508   P00846
    2       ATP6 IPI00552036       3 ENSG00000198899        7414     MT-ATP6      4508   P00846
    3       ATP6 IPI00552036       3 ENSG00000198899        7414     MT-ATP6      4508   P00846
    4       ATP6 IPI00954924       3 ENSG00000198899        7414     MT-ATP6      4508   P00846
    5       ATP6 IPI00743734       3 ENSG00000198899        7414     MT-ATP6      4508   P00846
    6       ATP6 IPI00654820       3 ENSG00000198899        7414     MT-ATP6      4508   P00846
    7       COX2 IPI00916440       1 ENSG00000198712        7421      MT-CO2      4513   P00403
    8       COX2 IPI00916440       1 ENSG00000198712        7421      MT-CO2      4513   P00403
    9       COX2 IPI00930721       1 ENSG00000198712        7421      MT-CO2      4513   P00403
    10      COX2 IPI00017510       1 ENSG00000198712        7421      MT-CO2      4513   P00403
```

I accomplished this by duplicating the data frame, deleting either .x or .y columns in one of the duplicate dataframes, renaming the column, and then using rbind to bring the two duplicate dataframes back together and using `unique()` to remove duplicated rows.

```
df2 <- df
#remove ipi_id.X  IPI ids from one DF
df$ipi_id.x <- NULL
colnames(df)[7] <- "ipi_id"
#remove ipi_id.y  IPI ids from the other DF
df2$ipi_id.y <- NULL
colnames(df2)[2] <- c("ipi_id")
#combine the dataframes
df3 <- rbind(df, df2)
df3 <- unique(df3)
```

This is clunky and I assume there is a better approach using `tidyr` or `reshape2`, but I did not find working examples and my clunky approach worked. Is there a better way to do this? A way to put this in one line?

Also, if my tags are poor please let me know for future posting.

Here is the dput variable version of my df:

```
    df <- structure(list(
    protein_id = structure(c(1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L), .Label = c("ATP6", "COX2"), class = "factor"), 
    ipi_id.x = structure(c(1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L), .Label = c("IPI00552036", "IPI00916440"), class = "factor"), 
    numbers = c(3L, 3L, 3L, 1L, 1L), 
    ensembl_id = structure(c(2L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 1L), .Label = c("ENSG00000198712", "ENSG00000198899"), class = "factor"), 
    hgnc_number = c(7414L, 7414L, 7414L, 7421L, 7421L), hgnc_symbol = structure(c(1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L), .Label = c("MT-ATP6", "MT-CO2"), class = "factor"), 
    entrez_id = c(4508L, 4508L, 4508L, 4513L, 4513L), ipi_id.y = structure(c(5L, 3L, 2L, 4L, 1L), .Label = c("IPI00017510", "IPI00654820", "IPI00743734", "IPI00930721", "IPI00954924"), class = "factor"), 
    uniprot = structure(c(2L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 1L), .Label = c("P00403", "P00846"), class = "factor")),
    .Names = c("protein_id", "ipi_id.x", "numbers", "ensembl_id", "hgnc_number", "hgnc_symbol", "entrez_id", "ipi_id.y", "uniprot"), class = "data.frame", 
    row.names = c(NA, -5L))
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There you go:

```
df %>% 
  unite(ipi_id, ipi_id.x, ipi_id.y, sep = "_") %>% 
  separate_rows(ipi_id, sep = "_")
```

what does it do?

`unite` puts ipi_id.x and ipi_id.y in one column separated by a "_" and removes the original variables ipi_id.x and ipi_id.y. Then we use tidyr's `separate_rows` which does exactly what you want: It takes a column as input, separates the values in it at "_" and duplicates the row if necessary.

Comment: Thanks! This is perfect. Annoyed I didn't see it myself first.